# Inserting a schema to another schema mongodb (mongoose)

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have two schemas that I want to be "connected" in the following way:
The first one is a `User` schema which includes the user's email , password and name:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
        name         : String
    }
});
```

The second one is an apartment (listing) schema which includes details about the apartment, and one of those details is the owner - which is a `User`:

```
var listingSchema = new Schema({
        street          : String,
        buildingNumber  : Number,
        apartmentNumber : Number,
        price           : Number,
        owner           :{
                type: Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
        }
});
```

Usually I would do something like so:

```
db.listings.insert({"street" : "Gordon", "buildingNumber" : 40, "apartmentNumber" : 69, "beds" : 3, "price" : 2000}
```

But what I would like to do now is something like this:

```
db.listings.insert({"street" : "Gordon", "buildingNumber" : 40, "apartmentNumber" : 69, "beds" : 3, "price" : 2000, "owner" : Idos})
```

I tried several approaches to passing this parameter but failed in all of them, how(can) it be achieved?

Comment: If you are using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) to access MongoDB, you should say so in your question.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko added to title and tag, thanks!

Comment: When doing `listing.insert{…, "owner" : Idos}` is `Idos` a model instance of  `userSchema`?

Comment: @laggingreflex you helped me alot without even knowing maybe haha. I instantiated  var Idos = db.users.findeOne()  and then used the insert like shown and it worked! I will edit the question

Comment: @laggingreflex if you wish, I will accept your answer (just add one) - what solved my problem was declaring a var Idos = db.users.find......   and then using listing.insert{…, "owner" : Idos} like you suggested. This works and my question is solved, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instantiating a `User` like this:
`var Idos = db.users.findOne()` // or `find(...)`
Then:

```
 db.listings.insert({"street" : "Dizingof", "buildingNumber" : 33, "apartmentNumber" : 63, "beds": 3,
"owner" : Idos})
```

and then inserting it to the DB like so:

```
db.listings.insert({"street" : "Gordon", "buildingNumber" : 40, "apartmentNumber" : 69, "beds" : 3, "price" : 2000, "owner" : Idos})
```